# how to disable the effect of ctx.rotate() on some shapes?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have some Images which i want to rotate and some which i dont want.
first see this code :

```
    var mainInterval = setInterval(() => {
        ctx.clearRect(-width,-height,width,height);
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,width,height);
        ctx.drawImage(pistolInv,width / 4,height - 60 * graphics,width / 8,60 * graphics);
        ctx.drawImage(submachinegunInv,width / 2,height - 60 * graphics,width / 8,60 * graphics);
        ctx.drawImage(ak47Inv,width / 4 * 3,height - 60 * graphics,width / 8,60 * graphics);
        ctx.rotate(angle);
        debugger;
        if(equippedGun != -1){
            var gun = new Image();
            gun.src = "assets/guns/" + guns[equippedGun] + ".png";
            ctx.drawImage(gun,width / 2,height / 2,120 * graphics,20 * graphics);
        }
        ctx.drawImage(player,width / 2 - (30 * graphics),height / 2 - (30 * graphics),60 * graphics,60 * graphics);
        ctx.drawImage(hand,width / 2 + (15 * graphics),height / 2 - (33 * graphics));
        ctx.drawImage(hand,width / 2 - (40 * graphics),height / 2 - (33 * graphics));
    },10);
```

in this example i want the 3 first images not to rotate and 4 second images be rotated.
but because of the interval the old rotate will effect on the 3 first images.
I think its because of that im rotating the whole ctx.
If yes is there anyway to rotate just shapes?

Comment: You know many ones asked this question but didnt have a complete and clean answer thats why im asking this question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `canvas` has been transformed, all further drawing go on the new position - previous drawing stay in the same place.

However, transformations stack, so one solution is to 'undo' the transform directly after drawing onto it.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("cnv");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var gp=0;

function animate() {

gp+=5;
gp%=360;

ctx.fillStyle='#fff'; // clear screen
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);

ctx.fillStyle='#f00'; // red squares
ctx.fillRect(50, 20, 10, 10);
ctx.fillRect(240, 20, 10, 10);

ctx.fillStyle='#0f0'; // gun
ctx.translate(150, 75);
ctx.rotate(gp * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.fillRect(-35,-10, 70, 20);
ctx.rotate(-gp * Math.PI / 180);
ctx.translate(-150, -75);

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="cnv" width="300" height="150" style="border:5px dashed black;border-radius:20px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @JMP i used it now and upvoted it.